# Разработка android приложения в Делфи Рио в связке с mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, delphi

Начал заниматься разработкой мобильного приложения на делфи 10.3 (рио). Суть вопроса заключается в удаленной работе с mysql, как это правильно организовать в android-приложении? Штатные компоненты Delphi (SQLconnection, FDconnection) не дружат с mysql, потому возникает необходимость создавать трехзвенную структуру приложения (Snap) или организовать веб-сервер на php для работы с mysql с последующей передачей данных на мобильное приложение. По мне Snap больше подходит для локальных сетей, а для интернет-связки лучше использовать вариант веб-сервера и через JSON получать данные в делфи-приложении. Вопрос заключается в том, какие тогда компоненты использовать в Delphi, чтобы поймать данные с веб-сервера и вывести в Grid или передать данные для вставки, изменения или удаления? Кто пробовал организовать подобную работу?

Answer (score 0):

организовать веб-сервер на php для работы с mysql с последующей передачей данных на мобильное приложение. для связи с веб-сервер используй Indy